# FlowDecision Designer components

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

My question is about the Flow Decision designer object.  Can I change the sides that the "True", "False", and Inputs come from?  Currently, True is always to the left, False on the Right, and input is at the top or the bottom.  Naturally some flows become very "Messy" because of this.  I know that I can always 'Not' the condition to switch the true and false, but that is sloppy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to swap those around.

Personally I would prefer the true option to go down and false to go sideways, that is the way I learned to draw flowcharts way back when I started programming but this is the way it is.

I suggest adding a request on User Voice [here](http://wf4.uservoice.com/forums/135016-workflow-designer).

Comment: Thanks for you answer!  Although I'm not too happy with your answer.  :/

Comment: Other than cretaing a complete new designer? No not that I am aware of.